# Get Link of Video and Set It to Video view?

Tags: android

I am doing this sort of code to play a Video in android...
I send the video link from previous activity by put extra.
And try to get the link in this page

```
video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

Do i misss something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This....

```
    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
 video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    video .setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    video .setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video .requestFocus();
    video .start();
```